# Intelij change equals and hashcode template for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

As you can see you can change and edit hashcode and equals templates for the java class. But not for Kotlin class. Is there any way to generate a custom equals method in Kotlin? maybe some plugin like [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13595-code-generator) one

[image]

Comment: Usually one uses `data class` in kotlin when they need a well behaving `equals` method. Would those not work for you?

Comment: We have legacy code converted from java . Data classes are not the option sadly

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `Generate code` (`Alt+Insert`, or `Ctrl+Shift+A` and start typing) and it's in there

[image: Generate Code popup menu]

Just make sure your cursor is in the class when you do `Generate` or you'll get different options